# Performance measures for 3d shape similarity

Tags: python, matching, descriptor, data-retrieval

I appreciate please if I got help with this:

my database is indexed like this:

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4    4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8]
```

where each number refers to a class, 0 refers to cat class and there are 10 cats for example,
what I'm doing is a query in order to retrieve similar shapes from the database, 5 queries are done,and their results are like this:

```
[list([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]) list([4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4])
 list([8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]) list([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
 list([5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5])]
```

so each list contains the top retrieved according to a constraint I already specified, but for sure here, there's twice 1 but it refers to different shapes but same class sure.

What I'm trying to figure now, is to do the performance measurements like Precision-recall, E-measure, Discount Cumulative Gain (DCG), Nearest Neighbor (NN), First-tier (Tier1), and Second-tier (Tier2).

The measures that are used in most the shape matching, and retrieval procedures.
Somehow I get the concept behind each term, but I'm lacking how to do it in my situation and on my data results.

I'm coding in Python.

Comment: Any assist here, please?

Comment: Till now I wasn't able to figure out how to deal with, I skip it in my work.